# Regex more than n number of characters, excluding pattern from count

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find a straight forward way to use regex to match any string n number of characters or longer while also allowing the ability to exclude a pattern from that count.

For example, if I have:

```
somename
somename-with-more-text
somename-with-even-more-text
somename2
somename-with-standard-naming
somename-ttt-ttt01-naming
somename-ggg-abc09-naming
```

I can use the regex `.{24,}` to return only strings with 24 or more characters, which returns:

```
somename-with-even-more-text
somename-with-standard-naming
somename-ttt-ttt01-naming
somename-ggg-abc09-naming
```

But now I'd like to also go a step further and exclude a pattern; a literal string or regex. For example, I'd like to exclude `ttt-ttt01` or maybe `[a-z]{3}\d{2}`. So I would be left with:

```
somename-with-even-more-text
somename-with-standard-naming
somename-ggg-abc09-naming
```

or

```
somename-with-even-more-text
somename-with-standard-naming
```

I've gotten nowhere fast trying a variety of solutions...some examples of failed attempts:

```
.{24,}(?<!b[a-z]{3}\d{2})
```

```
^(?!ttt01)(.{24,})
```

```
^\b(.{24,})\b(?<!ttt01)
```

```
.{24,}(?!ttt01\b)\b\w+
```

Comment: `^(?!.*ttt01).{24,}`

Comment: Use: `^(?!.*[a-z]{3}\d{2}).{24,}`

Comment: You just need to add a negative lookahead like this: `(?!.*ttt-ttt01)` so it will look like this: `(?!.*ttt-ttt01).{24,}`. If the negative lookahead finds whats insinde the brackets, the whole regex wont match. I added `.*` before the `ttt-ttt01`. It means it finds everything (`.` stands for every character and the `*` say's it can be there 0 to unlimited times). So the `ttt-ttt01` can be at any certain position. A lookahead acts like a own regex, starting at the position where you add it.

Comment: Thank you all. If anyone would like to convert comments to answer/description, I'll accept. All of those work/make sense.